# Using Workflow Foundation with EF for message processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, workflow-foundation

Just wondering if Workflow Foundation is suitable for my problem.

The system will be used to process messages in XML format.
Based on message contents the system can send other messages to related systems or, in case of incomplete data, query them for additional information. Some messages have quite elaborate workflow with multiple states so this is why am I thinking of leveraging WF as then the message processing workflows would be easier to modify and understand due to visual workflow designer

In some cases missing data has to be entered by users manually. ASP.NET MVC application with EF will be used for that.

Is the WF suitable for this task?

I see these possible problems:

1. Getting all messages that are in certain state;
2. Editing the messages directly and notifying WF to resume the workflow, possibly even from different step;
3. WF should not persist the message content within its state and persist/load them from database when needed; In fact I do not think it should persist anything that cannot be changed by EF directly. I guess I would need custom persistence service for that, wouldn't this take too much effort?
4. Everything must be unit-testable.

Comment: As much as I can see, WF seems to be the right choice for your project. But why do you think #1 and #2 can be problems?